# Selenium java automation - how do i input values into an empty cell

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am writing an automation test script in Java for Selenium. One of the scenarios requires me to input a value into a dynamic table that contains an empty cell (ex: as shown below highlighted in red box). I have tried using document.getElementxpath(locator).value="xxxxx" but am unable to set it. Can someone help me on this:

[Empty cells in a table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RMZK.jpg)

Comment: `<td>` do not have value attributes.  What you are trying to set is the `innerHTML` or the `innerText`

Comment: pls suggest how to set inner HTML for the below. Please note "<td>/td>" is the empty cell i am referring to:
<div class="widgetAndIconsAndContexthelpWrapper FormFieldWidget" id="id="Link_Item_to_Shopping_Item">
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr id="" class="even selected">
   <td class="readonly"><a href="javascript:;" class="gwt-Anchor">123456</a> </td>
   <td class="readonly"><a href="javascript:;" class="gwt-Anchor">Test_item</a> </td>
   <td></td>
   <td class="readonly"><i class="material-icons stb" title="Delete Reference">cancel</i> </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>